# Why does javascript 'if statements' return undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, palindrome

This is more of a 'why does this happen' question than a trouble shooting question.

I am trying to create a function that tests whether a word is a palindrome. I thought initially that I can use an if statement it compare the word and when it is reversed. However the if statement gave me undefined. When I compared it regularly (word === reverseWord), it came back with a truth or false. My question is what is going on in the if statement for it do wonk out? Thanks!

```
const palindromes = function(word) {
    *//Turn word into an array*
    var arrWord = Array.from(word);
    *//Reverse the array*
    var reversedWord = arrWord.reverse();

    *//This is true*
    return arrWord === reversedWord;

    //But this is undefined?
    if (arrWord === reversedWord) {true} else {false};
}
```

Comment: where is the `return`?

Comment: Make it a runnable snippet so that we can all agree what is happening or not.

Comment: You are not returning anything in the if as well as in the else, make sure you do it this way: 
`if (arrWord === reversedWord) {return true} else {return false}`

Comment: omg, I'm so embarrassed.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its returning undefined because you are not using `return` keyword anywhere.

Another mistake you are making is that you are comparing two arrays which reference same object in memory it `arrWord === reversedWord` will always return `true`.

Convert `word` to array using `split('')` and `reverse()` it. And then `join('')`. And finally compare reversed string and `word`

```js
const palindromes = function(word) {
    var reversedWord = word.split('').reverse().join('');
    console.log(word === reversedWord);
    if (word === reversedWord) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    };
}

console.log(palindromes("aba"))
console.log(palindromes("ba"))
```

The code can be reduced to a single line.

```js
const palindromes = (word) => word.split('').reverse().join('') === word 

console.log(palindromes("aba"))
console.log(palindromes("ba"))
```

Comment: Wow that was fast response. Thanks so much for your help Maheer! Yeah, I realized that something was wrong when everything was returning true lol

Comment: @user12962969 You are welcome. Accept the answer if you are satisfied with it